# How to post a custom value from laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add a value from controller and send it to mysql along with the other input that I get from the view. How do I supposed to do it?

I tried using array_merge, tried to put them at the same variable and send it with Laravel's create but to no avail.

Here's the code

**The Value**

```php
 $id = 0;
 $id++;

 $time = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
 $date = new Carbon( $time );
 $d = $date->format('Y');

   $fmipa = 0;
   $fkh = 0;
   $lastNumber = 0;
   $fk = $request->get('fakultas');
   if($fk == 'FMIPA'){
     $fmipa++;
     $fk = 42;
     if($fmipa < 10){
        $fmipa="00". $fmipa;
        $lastNumber = $fmipa;
     }else if($fmipa < 100){
        $fmipa="0" . $fmipa;
        $lastNumber = $fmipa;
     }else{
        $fmipa = $fmipa;
        $lastNumber = $fmipa;
     }
   }else{
     $fkh++;
     $fk = 41;
     if($fkh < 10){
       $fkh="00". $fkh;
       $lastNumber = $fkh;
     }else if($fkh < 100){
       $fkh="0" . $fkh;
       $lastNumber = $fkh;
     }else{
       $fkh = $fkh;
       $lastNumber = $fkh;
     }
    }

$nim = $d . $fk . "101" . $lastNumber;
```

**The Store() function**

```php
    $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), array(
     'nama' => 'required',
     'alamat' => 'required',
     'fakultas' => 'required',
    ));

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return response()->json([
        'error'    => true,
        'messages' => $validator->errors(),
      ], 422);
    }

   $mahasiswa = Dashboard::create($request->all() + ['nim' => $nim]);


   return response()->json([
      'error' => false,
      'mhs'  => $mahasiswa,
   ], 200);
```

I seperate them to make it easy to read, but in case you're wondering the value's code is right in the store() function.

I expect it to post the value to the database and yet what I got from XHR's Response is

> 500 Internal Server Error

and

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'nim' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because your table dashboards of column **nim** is not nullable and it does not have a default value.

Inside your model Dashboard

```
protected $fillable = [... , 'nim'];
```

When you tried to create a dashboard, you are not giving value to the **nim**, which is causing the error.

If you do want the nim column to be nullable, you can add the functionality in you migration file.

**Migration File**

```
...
$table->string('nim')->nullable();
...
```

Re run your migration using php artisan migrate:refresh

If you want it to manually check, you can try in the DashboardController

```
//If request does not have nim
if(!$request->has('nim') && !empty($request->nim)){
    $request->nim = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace store function as below

```
$dashboard = new Dashboard();
$dashboard->nama = $request->nama;
$dashboard->alamat = $request->alamat;
$dashboard->fakultas = $request->fakultas;
$dashboard->nim = $nim;
$dashboard->save();
```